# Executing remote command and saving input to file

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, telnet, remote-execution

I need to access to multiple hosts through SSH, execute a specific command (`show ms info`) and capture the output to a file. I need to copy that file back to my linux machine

I want to use `ssh` and `expect` to supply the password

My problem is saving the output to a text file and looping around 100 machines simultaneously.

Comment: If you can use Perl, check [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::OpenSSH::Parallel).

Answer (score 4):

It is more straightforward than you think:

```
host1 $ ssh user@host2 ls > remote-output.txt
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa':
host1 $ ls
remote-output.txt
host1 $
```

To do it for multiple hosts, I suggest using [ssh-agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent) and setting up autorization keys:

```
$ ssh-agent bash
$ ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa:
$ for h in host1 host2;do ssh $h ls > $h.txt; done
$ ls
host1.txt host2.txt
$
```

Comment: thanks ALOT!! stil having problems with the multiple hosts, but its from the machine more or less